# How to Configure login UI for IdentityServer4?

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

Examples I find for IdentityServer4 use [MVC](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI) for login UI. When a OpenIdConnect implicit client hits the 'authorization_endpoint' (example 'http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize') it gets redirected to the [AccountController](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/release/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs) Login action. How would you configure IdentityServer4 to use a different controller or UI for as the login page?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Under the ConfigureServices method (in Startup) add in a SetupIdentityServer options method:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(*SetupIdentityServer*)
        .AddSigningCredential(...)
        .AddValidationKeys()
        .AddConfigurationStore(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(""))
        .AddOperationalStore(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(""))
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

...where SetupIdentityServer is the name of a method where you can set the login url:

```
private static void SetupIdentityServer(IdentityServerOptions identityServerOptions)
{
    identityServerOptions.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Controller/Action";
}
```