# How do I set custom redirect value for login page in IdentityService v4?

Tags: c#, authentication, identityserver4

I've made the following config.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc();

  services.AddIdentityServer(SetupIdentityServer)
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryClients(GetClients)
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(GetIdentities)
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(GetApis)
    .AddTestUsers(GetUsers);

  services.AddAuthentication("TheCookie")
    .AddCookie("TheCookie", _ =>
    {
      _.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
      _.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });

  ...
}

private static void SetupIdentityServer(IdentityServerOptions options)
{
  options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Security/Credentials";
  options.UserInteraction.LoginReturnUrlParameter = "bbb";
  options.UserInteraction.CustomRedirectReturnUrlParameter = "aaa";
}
```

However, when I access a page that requires authorization, I get 404 because I'm forwarded to the default */Account/Login*" controller/action. I can confirm that the *SetupIdentityServer* is invoked because it hit a breaky there. Still, the URL in the browser stays default and the return page is the one I'm trying to access instead of the phony setup above.

The [docs for IdS4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/options.html#userinteraction) don't explain very much and I can't figure out what I'm missing. I've tried to follow the set up like [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42404715/1525840).

I suspect that it's got to do with my client, which is set up as follows.

```
private static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients => new[]
{
  new Client
  {
    ClientId = "Website",
    ClientName = "The Client",
    ClientUri = "http://identityserver.io",

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

    RedirectUris = {"http://localhost:5000/security/credentials"},
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"http://localhost:5000/index.html"},
    AllowedCorsOrigins = {"http://localhost:5000", "https://localhost:44300"},

    AllowedScopes =
    {
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
      IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
    }
  }
};
```

It's my understanding that the grant type *implicit* is supposed to be used for SPAs while MVC-style login is being governed by the setup is managed by default simply specifying it as I did in *SetupIdentityServer*. I sense that the issue might be somewhere there but googling for stuff about clients' types gave me more headache than clarity.

Comment: The redirect URL will be defined on the default cookie scheme but in some circumstances IDS4 will need to know where to go too, hence the duplication.

Comment: It could be a bug: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2866